# explicit large gap for consecutive zeros of the Riemann zeta function

Tags: riemann-zeta-function, effective-results, nt.number-theory

In Theorem 9.12, Titchmarsh (The Theory of the Riemann Zeta Function) proved that

For every large positive T, $\zeta(s)$ has a zero $\beta+i\gamma$ satisfying 
$$
|\gamma-T|<\frac{A}{\log\log\log T}
$$

Is it possible to determine $A$ and $T$ without assuming the Riemann hypothesis?

Or

Are there any other known results (with explicit) around this question?

Answer (score 6):

Theorem 9.12 in Titchmarsh says (in his shorthand style) *there exists* a constant $A$ such that *for all sufficiently large T*, (etc.)

The proof uses the Borel-Caratheodory theorem, and can be made effective if you really really want it. Titchmarsh has a series of seven successive constants $A_1, A_2,\ldots A_6, A$ with the final $A$ being the constant you reference above.  This is not conditional on the Riemann Hypothesis.

It's not clear how your actual question relates to your title.

Answer (score 0):

do you want to determine T also? I thought the result should hold for all T?

Comment: @Dierk. If so, it would be better, if not just to know if it is not large. for example if $A=1$ and $T<10^{10}$, it's OK.